# Getting "Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed"

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created several Data Access Objects according to [this Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html), but I'm having trouble with one of them. I run some queries on it when the app resumes, and I occasionally get the error in the title. Specifically I run execute three methods of the form:

```
public List<Event> getPendingEvents() {
    openReadable();
    List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();

    Cursor cursor = localDb.query(EventTable.TABLE_EVENT,
            allColumns, allColumns[8] + " = ?", new String[] {"pending"}, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst(); // crash here:  Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        events.add(cursorToEvent(cursor));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return events;
}
```

And then I close the database connection after they have all run. Why would the connection pool close after the query? I'm struggling to think of a reason. Could it somehow be related to the size of the database file? The tables specifically are and will always be very small (< 50 records), but could the other tables have an impact? My only other thought is that it has something to do with how onResume works.

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: twice `openReadable();` maybe remove one of them?!

Comment: @WarrenFaith Removed one of them (no idea why it was there twice...), but it wasn't the issue. OpenReadable actually checks to see if it's already open, so the second call did nothing.

Comment: Are you sure cursor is not null and cursor.getCount() gives you a value > 0?
Maybe the issue is in the query and you're not getting any data at all.

Comment: @fasteque Added in a check. The issue is hard to reproduce, so I may not know for a while whether it is fixed or not, so I still appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Where is `localDb` assigned?

Comment: @LS_dev in the constructor of the DAO